# Can only get "did well in class" recommendation letters, how can I make the best of it?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter

I am applying to a master's program, and I had two professors that knew me well that agreed to recommend me. Both have expertise in the field I'm applying to. I took all their relevant elective courses and got As. I also worked with one of them as a teaching assistant, and with the other as a research volunteer on a relevant project. And they supervised my graduation project (also on a relevant topic to my MSc). Unfortunately, I lost contact with them, one is very ill, and the other left the university and went abroad, and he is pretty much unreachable now.

Now I can only get recommendations from professors who are not specialists in the field, and who have nothing to say of me except that I "did well in class". They are kind enough to let me write what I want in the letter so long as it's factually true. How do I make the best of this? I want to include something about my teaching and research experience/grad project in the letters, but these professors haven't worked with me directly on that, can I mention it anyway?

Comment: Don't make assumptions about the earlier writers and what they can do. The university can probably help you with both of them.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I lost contact with them, one is very ill, and the other left the university and went abroad, and he is pretty much unreachable now." Does "pretty much unreachable" mean that you don't know their current email address or that you asked multiple people at the university if they can help you get in touch with them and they all said no?

Comment: Thank you, guys, for your comments. I tried to contact the second professor multiple times on his emails, and phone but he didn't respond. I can keep trying, however, I should probably assume the worst and be prepared for it, because I had a friend who also needed his recommendation and contacted him shortly before he left and he promised to recommend her, however he stopped responding and didn't upload the recommendation till the last minute and she had to scramble to find a substitute.

Comment: The other professor has been seriously ill for a long time & is not expected to be back within the timeline of my application (I'm applying by next month). Even if he did, it would be in very bad taste of me to ask him to recommend me on a tight timeline when he would be just recovering from a serious illness.

Comment: All that to say, I need to assume the worst and make the best of what I do have.

Comment: It's probably not very productive to keep trying to call him when he doesn't respond, but it may make sense to ask one of his colleagues if they know how to get in touch with him. The answer might likely be no, but given that the difference between a strong letter and a generic letter could make or break your application, I would say it's worth giving a try. Of course you are right that the story with the other letter does not bode well for you.

Comment: Yes, I'll definitely do that. Thank you. However, since he has a history of ghosting students and not uploading recommendations to the last minute. I'll be prepared for the worst and work on my other references as much as I can.

Comment: I've +1ed this as an important question.  I left the last university where I worked in a bit of a hurry, and the university shut down my e-mail account immediately (actually while I was still officially on leave of absence, rather than fully gone).  Former colleagues passed on one reference request from a recent graduate to me, but I'm sure there must have been others needing a reference and scratching their heads as to how to contact me.

Comment: Are there other people in the lab/research group/institute that would be allowed to write the letters and that know you, maybe not quite as good as the professors, but good enough to say something on your TA or research experience in their letters?

Comment: @DanielHatton Thank you for sharing. I'll certainly try to contact my professor through his colleagues if I they agree to help. I hope it doesn't appear like I'm spamming him, though :"D Because I do have his personal, and new institutional email addresses and I have already tried emailing him.

Comment: @Sabine In the research project that I volunteered in, there were my two professors, other graduate students, some TAs and some RAs. I think they would be very weak references; probably as week as the ones I already have (the did well in class) references. In terms of TA work and grad project, no one was directly involved other than my partner- who co-taught and did the GP with me- and the professors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would make sure that the people who have agreed to write for you can speak to your TA experience and thesis project. Let them know that you would usually ask A (sick professor) to write about your TA experience in the department, but since A is sick, you have included your TA evals and the course syllabus and are wondering if they can add a paragraph about your TA work. Similar logic applies to your thesis. They will think of it as “helping a sick colleague who can’t write the letter.”

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I thought of that, but I wasn't sure how I'd put it in and make it sound relevant. I was also wondering if it would look suspicious that a professor is praising my work on something they weren't directly involved in and that is somewhat outside their specialty.

Comment: @green_bean: it wouldn't look suspicious if they also explained that the person who would usually comment on it is unable to.

Comment: This one for sure - committees reviewing this kind of thing understand extenuating circumstances - academia is also small enough that they may know your ill professor

Comment: @green_bean have you tried talking to them in person? Or at least by phone?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to do that.

Comment: @lupe I hope they do :"D

Comment: @fectin Yes, I called the second professor a few times, and emailed him. I can't meet him in person because he's abroad. I also don't want to seem like I'm spamming him.

Comment: @green_bean have you tired talking to the people who have agreed to write letters for you in person?

Comment: @green_bean One thing that you could see is if the letter writers would contact the sick/missing professors on your behalf, by phone or e-mail, and incorporate their feedback. The absent professors would be more likely to respond, as it would take less work for them. The letter could say the writer spoke to the unavailable professors and relay their opinion.

Comment: @fectin sorry misunderstood your question. I talked to them only once to ask for the recommendation. They asked me to write a draft and send it for approval. So, I was thinking I'd write something about my TA work and GP and talk to them in person to explain why I wrote that.

Comment: @user71659 since they gave me permission to write my own letter. I was thinking I'd go ahead and include the info I want then talk to them to explain why I included it. I'd maybe ask them to help me contact professor B if they can. professor A, though, is currently hospitalized, so no shot.